# C# Tuple not returning value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, return, tuples, task

it's my first time using tuple's so i might be doing something completely wrong or just missed something small. I used to have repetitive code :

```
            if (!B1Fturn)
            {
                if (B1turn)
                {
                    FixCall(b1Status, ref b1Call, ref b1Raise, 1);
                    FixCall(b1Status, ref b1Call, ref b1Raise, 2);
                    Rules(2, 3, "Bot 1", ref b1Type, ref b1Power, B1Fturn, b1Status);
                    AutoCloseMsb.Show("Bot 1 Turn", "Turns", thinkTime);
                    AI(2, 3, ref bot1Chips, ref B1turn, ref  B1Fturn, b1Status, b1Power, b1Type);
                    turnCount++;
                    B1turn = false;
                    B2turn = true;
                }
            }
            if (B1Fturn && !b1Folded)
            {
                bools.RemoveAt(1);
                bools.Insert(1, null);
                maxLeft--;
                b1Folded = true;
            }
            if (B1Fturn || !B1turn)
            {
                await CheckRaise(1, 1);
                B2turn = true;
            }
```

and i had this copied and pasted 5 times so i decided to put it all in a method and just paste the method 5 times instead. So i started doing it but i realized i will need to await some methods so i went for `async Task<some input>` however i need to get back some values a few booleans and int's .2 options either return or use ref/out. Ref/out are not allowed in async methods anyway so only return is left. The things is that i needed a few different types of data to be returned so i needed something that does that (it was the Tuple). I created one method using Tuple :

```
async Task<Tuple<bool, bool, bool>> Rotating(bool tempTurn, bool permaTurn, bool folded, string name, Label Status, int botCall, int botRaise, int start, int end, int current, bool next, double power, double type, int chips)
    {
        if (!permaTurn)
        {
            if (tempTurn)
            {
                FixCall(Status, ref botCall, ref botRaise, current);
                FixCall(Status, ref botCall, ref botRaise, start);
                Rules(start, end, name, ref type, ref power, permaTurn,Status);
                AutoCloseMsb.Show(name + " Turn", "Turns", thinkTime);
                AI(start, end, ref chips, ref tempTurn, ref  permaTurn, Status, power, type);
                turnCount++;
                tempTurn = false;
                next = true;
            }
        }
        if (permaTurn && !folded)
        {
            bools.RemoveAt(current);
            bools.Insert(current, null);
            maxLeft--;
            folded = true;
        }
        if (permaTurn || !tempTurn)
        {
            await CheckRaise(current, current);
            next = true;
        }
        return new Tuple<bool, bool, bool>(tempTurn, permaTurn, next);
    }
```

As you can see it says return bool,bool,bool and after this the values that i need to get. However i didn't work out that well next didn't got it's value changed if i put breakpoint on the `return` line from false next turns to true, but once it quit's the method it's back to default false . Same goes for the other 2 booleans. Why ? What am i doing wrong how to fix this.

- P.S i also needed to return a few int's as i mentioned earlier but i removed them for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited after conversation in chat:
You can await the async function which will give back a tuple, use it like this:

```
var r = await Test (x, y); // x,y for example, Test returns Tuple
Now you can access r.Item1 and r.Item2
```

Comment: the first code in my question was used 5 times just b1turn b1fturn and etc were change with b2turn b2fturn... b5turn,b5fturn like this also your code will give me not awaitable bool

Comment: I do not understand what exactly happens to next and what you tried with setting a breakpoint. May you clearify?

Comment: Im not sure what you dont understand. Next must come out with value of true.

Comment: Yes, but for that to happen, this: `permaTurn || !tempTurn` must be true. I cannot see any actual function call, so I cannot say if it ever is. Do I misunderstand anything?

Comment: I dont see any reason for this to change the situation but anyway it will always come out as true

Comment: Consider permaTurn and tempTurn being both false. Next will never be touched. It might be my fault, but please go ahead and completely describe your problem again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100089/discussion-between-nikxda-and-kopelence).